# How many weeks are inside of two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have starting dates and ending dates in my database (MySQL). 
How can I get the answer, how many weeks(or days) are inside of those 2 dates? (mysql or php)

For example I have this kind of database:

Started and | will_end
2009-12-17 | 2009-12-24
2009-12-12 | 2009-12-26
...

Update to the question:
How to use DATEDIFF?
How can I make this to work? or should I use DATEDIFF completly differently?

SELECT DATEDIFF('Started ','will_end') AS 'Duration' FROM my_table WHERE id = '110';

Comment: Do you mean whole weeks? Like for instance going from Thursday in one week to Thursday next week actually contains no whole weeks, but consists of 7 days so the second Thursday is one week later than the first? When dealing with time and date, please be precise in your specifications (no pun intended.)

Comment: This appears to have been reasked by @jsk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946490/how-to-use-datediff-how-many-days-are-inside-of-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) which returns the difference in days between two dates, since MySQL 4.1.1.

Do note that, as per the manual, `DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)` returns `expr1 – expr2` expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. *Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation*.

Answer (score 2):

If the two columns `$d1` and `$d2` store unix timestamp obtained from `time()` then this simple line suffices:

```
$diffweek = abs($d1 - $d2) / 604800;
```

Otherwise if the columns are of DATETIME type, then:

```
$diffweek = abs(strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2)) / 604800;
```

p/s: 604800 is the number of seconds in a week (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)

p/s2: you might want to `intval($diffweek)` or `round($diffweek)`

Comment: -1, this loses precision and is complicated when there's at least one other perfectly reasonable way to do it correctly and simply.

Comment: yeah yeah .. it's very very very superbly complicated .. it's plain obvious, right? hands down ...

Comment: You are conflating the meanings of 'very very very superbly complicated' and 'more complicated than a better solution'.

Comment: True there aren't exactly 24 hours in a day but wouldn't the error be tiny?

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the number of days and dividing by seven won't give you the number of weeks between the two dates. Instead it will return the result of division by 7 that doesn't always correspond to the number of weeks between the two dates when thinking in terms of the number of weeks in the ISO calculation.

For example, given `start_date = "2010-12-26"` and `end_date = "2011-01-25"` you will be going through W51,52,01,02,03,04 and those are 6 weeks as per ISO, but if you simply calculate the difference and divide by 7, you'll get 5.

The issue appears when the start date and end date belong to different years.

The best way to do the calculation is to get the last week number of the `start_date` year and it should refer to the December, 28.

```
function weeks($ladate2,$ladate3) {
    $start_week= date("W",strtotime($ladate2));
    $end_week= date("W",strtotime($ladate3));
    $number_of_weeks= $end_week - $start_week;

    $weeks=array();
    $weeks[]=$start_week;
    $increment_date=$ladate2;
    $i="1";

    if ($number_of_weeks<0){
        $start_year=date("Y",strtotime($ladate2));
        $last_week_of_year= date("W",strtotime("$start_year-12-28"));
        $number_of_weeks=($last_week_of_year-$start_week)+$end_week;
    }

    while ($i<=$number_of_weeks)
    {
        $increment_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ladate2. " +$i week"));
        $weeks[]=date("W",strtotime($increment_date));

        $i=$i+1;
    }

    return $weeks;
}

function diff_weeks($ladate2,$ladate3) {
    $weeks=weeks($ladate2,$ladate3);
    $diff_weeks=count($weeks);

    return $diff_weeks;
}
```

Best regards,
Manikam

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TO_DAYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) function on each date and subtract the two to calculate the difference in days.

Answer (score 0):

[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Find the days and divide by 7

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
  $dayDif    = date('z',strtotime('2009-12-17)') - date('z',strtotime('2009-12-24)');
  $numWeeks  = $dayDif / 7;
?>
```

The z option for php's date function gives you the day of the year (0 - 365). By subtracting the two values you find how many days between dates. Then factor by seven for the number of weeks.

Read this page closely, the date() function is rich. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: and what if the years are different? .. pls, programmers should be thinking all these what-ifs when coding a function. don't just crop the acceptable inputs based on 2-3 examples ...

Comment: Ah, great point. The unix timestamp approach works cross year.