# How to use DATEDIFF? How many days are inside of two dates

Tags: php, mysql, database, datediff, days

How to use DATEDIFF? How can I make this to work? or should I use DATEDIFF completly differently?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('Started ','will_end') AS 'Duration' FROM my_table WHERE id = '110';
```

I try to get answer, how many days are inside of two dates.

I would like to get an aswer like: 
Duration = 7 days;

I have this kind of database:

Started   | will_end
2009-12-17 | 2009-12-24
2009-12-12 | 2009-12-26

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946002/how-many-weeks-are-inside-of-two-dates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `will_end` first, `started` second:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF('2009-12-24', '2009-12-17') 

---
  7
```

Also, remove the single quotes from your field names:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(will_end, started) AS Duration
FROM    my_table
WHERE   id = 110
```

, or replace them with the backticks:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(`will_end`, `started`) AS `Duration`
FROM    `my_table`
WHERE   `id` = 110
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting a `NULL` result? You have the column names in single quotes in your query, which means you are passing the strings `'Started '` and `'will_end'` to `DATEDIFF` rather than the column values. Try removing the single quotes, and you will start to see some results:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Started, will_end) AS Duration FROM my_table WHERE id = '110';
```

Note that this will give you a negative result. To get a positive result, reverse the order of the columns:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(will_end, Started) AS Duration FROM my_table WHERE id = '110';
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the order

DATEDIFF('will_end','Started')

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 parameter to be passed in 
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

so your code would be 
DATEDIFF ( dd , 'Started ','will_end' )

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: The question is about `MySQL`

Comment: Er... what's this got to do with MYSQL?